# Calculating velocity and position with integrals

Tags: definite-integrals

A ball is dropped from a height of 3000 feet. Its velocity after t seconds is $v(t)=-78t$.

a) How fast is the ball dropping after 5 seconds?

b) Determine the position function $s=s(t)$.

For a), I multiplied $64$ by $5$ and got $320$. But, I'm currently stuck on b); I got $s(t)=-32t^2+c$, but I can't figure out how to calculate the $c$ value, because there is no $s(0)=0$. Thank you!

Comment: It says it is dropped from height of $1000$ ft.

Comment: s(0) is the height at time t=0. The ball was dropped from 1000 ft, so s(0) = 1000

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out

Comment: @Julia Remark: Usually a velocity has units, i.e. $\frac{\textrm{miles}}{\textrm{hour}}$ And why have you changed the numbers?